# How to POST NSData on server using MKNetworkKIt

Tags: objective-c, soap, mknetworkkit

Currently our application is using `ASIFormDataRequest` to post data on server.

I was using

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:urlWeb];
[request setShouldPresentAuthenticationDialog:NO];
[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction" value:@"http://something"];
[request setUsername:@"ABC"]; 
[request setPassword:@"XYZ"]; 
[request setDomain:@"LMN"];
[request appendPostData:[strSoapEnvl dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

BUT `ASIHTTPRequest` is not supporting ARC. So I have decided to use *MKNetworkKIt* as replacement. But I am not getting any sample code to do the same.

I have seen downloaded code from github of Mugunth Kumar but there they used `NSMutableDictionary` object as parameter in `MKNetworkOperation`.

Answer (score 1):

For SOAP, you should use something like this.

```
[op setCustomPostDataEncodingHandler:^NSString *(NSDictionary *postDataDict) {

    DDXMLDocument *doc = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:[rootElement XMLString] 
                                                      options:0 
                                                        error:nil];
    return [doc XMLString];

} forType:@"text/xml"];
```

`NSDictioanry` is for JSON, or URL or x-plist encoding which are infact the most common encoding types.